# Setting width of table cell contents based on available width

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table whose cells contain, among other things, spans, like this:

```
...
<td>
    <span style="height: 20px; width: 20px; margin-left: 2px;">
    <span style="height: 20px; width: 20px; margin-left: 2px;">
    <span style="height: 20px; width: 20px; margin-left: 2px;">
</td>
...
```

I'm looking for a way to shrink the width of those spans, rather than line wrap them, when the containing table cell is too narrow to show them all on one line. I tried playing around with setting the spans' `max-width` to `20px` and then using a percent for the width, but that does not work because the table cell tries to be only as wide as its contents.

The minimum table cell width would be the width needed to display the header on 1 line.

For the visual types, here's what I currently have when there is enough width:

[image]

Here's what I currently have when there is not enough width:

[image]

And here's what I would like it to look like when there is not enough width for each span to be a full 20px:

[image]

In case it's not obvious, the spans are the colored squares in the `TXEs`, `RDBs`, and `RavenNets` columns.

Comment: +1 for asking the question clearly, concisely, and with mockups of what you have and what you need! :)

Comment: Thanks. I figured no one would want to look at my FF-only HTML source code, and you know what they say about a picture's worth in words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a satisfactory pure-CSS way to do what I wanted. I already had an application config file implemented (like a `.ini` file, more or less) so I just added my desired width to this config. It's not a general-purpose solution but it fits my requirements just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<td nowrap>` or `<td style="white-space:nowrap;">` to avoid the wrapping. A table cell should generally expand to fit its contents, unless it is allowed to wrap, or you have constrained its width in some other way.

Comment: I did try both of those (they do the same thing) but that doesn't work, as I would expect. I have (currently) set an explicit width on the contents of the cell and, yes, the cell width is constrained - that's why I need to shrink its contents in the first place.

Comment: @bears - scary name! - Well, thought I would try the obvious first. Setting width works only on block -level elements, not on spans. What is the content of your spans? How is the color set? Images? BG colors? &nbsp;?

Comment: The spans are empty. Until about 30 minutes before I posted my question, the spans were divs that were `float: left` ed; they behaved exactly the same. I did also play around with using `display: inline-block` to this end. The color is set using a `-moz-linear-gradient` background.

Comment: Reading more carefully... you want the boxes to be 20 pixels, unless they can't be, and then they should shrink - right? You might be able to do this with script - after the page loads, check the width of the table cell, and then adjust your boxes accordingly, but it might be a pain, and there might be some ugly flashing. Or you could try using a single-row table for your boxes. Give each cell a width of 25% and they should adapt to fit.

Comment: To your first question: right. I could do this with script, but it would be really ugly, especially since the number of boxes can change between page loads. In an ideal world I would solve this by attaching a listener to the table row, fired by a `heightChanged` event - but this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting a min-width on the td? or a wrapper div inside the td, but outside the spans?

Comment: The `td` width is the issue here. The problem isn't that the `td` is getting too narrow. On the contrary, the `td` is exactly as wide as it needs to be. The problem is squeezing the `td`'s contents so that they don't wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This sorta kinda seems to do something close to what you want in Firefox 3.6. The crucial requirement seems to be that the table's width cannot be in pixels.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">

<style type="text/css">
    .indicator {
        display:block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        min-width:8px;
        max-width:300px;
        width:100%;
    }

    .indicator li {
        border:outset 2px;
        display:inline-block;
        height:80px;
        min-width:2px;
        max-width:80px;
        padding:0 0 0 2px;
        width:25%;
    }

    .ok    { background:#0f0 } .caution { background:#ff0 }
    .alert { background:#f00 } .inactive { background:#0ff }

    table { width:100% }
    td { width:100% }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<table><tr><td>
<ul class="indicator">
    <li class="ok"></li> <li class="caution"></li>
    <li class="alert"></li> <li class="inactive"></li>
</ul>
</td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```